# What is the name for wireframe-like projection images of technical objects?

Tags: style-identification

What do you call wireframe-like projection images of technical objects?

Like the rocket images below:

[image]

This is not an actual wireframe because empty spaces are not filled with a grid; only notable features are displayed.

Comment: Blueprint or diagram would both work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two words: *"Technical Drawing"*.

Simply enter *"techical drawing"* in the search-box of your favorite search engine. You'll find a whole universe of such *"drawings"*.

**EDIT**

Related to your example: that's a technical drawing comparing Russian rocket type heights. They are drawn according to ISO 128 *Technical drawings — General principles of presentation*. (In case you're curious, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_drawing has some more info on that.)

[image: example via sciencedirect.com]

The above example is from http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576509000307 but *NASA* has some nice technical drawings too (even old ones like http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4308/p256.htm) and don't miss out on [historicspacecraft.com](http://historicspacecraft.com/) which has modern versions including color illustrations based on technical drawings.

[image: example via historicspacecraft.com]

Answer (score 0):

It's merely an Illustration. - Pen & Ink, Line Drawing, etc.

I don't know that I would even go so far as to call it a "technical drawing" since all the technical aspects aren't drawn. It's merely a line drawing.

Comment: Though it may not be used strictly for engineering purposes, the style is still usually referred to as technical.

Comment: I would not call that image a technical drawing. It's simply a line drawing.

Comment: Technical drawings are line drawings executed with a keen eye on scale and usually annotated as such. Within the very broad category of [line drawings](https://www.google.com/search?q=line+drawing&tbm=isch), the overall style of the OP's example is extremely similar to the sub-category of technical line drawings. How about "technical style"? Agree to disagree perhaps.

Comment: You are not going to change my mind, plainclothes. That's simply a line drawing, not a technical drawing.

Comment: I didn't suppose I would ;) I'm just stating my case (and presumably e-sushi's) for the community at large.